# Adding AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m info in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, annotations, appdelegate

Hi I am just starting in swift and taking an iPad app and creating a iphone version.
I am trying to add annotations to a map in Swift and need to add so info to AppDelegate.h and .m to get it to work but in Swift there are is no AppDelegate.h or .m . How do I get this to work?

Here is what has to go into the AppDelegates

```
.h

 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @class AnnotationViewController;

  @interface AnnotationAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

 }

  @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

  @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet AnnotationViewController *viewController;

  @end



.m

 #import "AnnotationAppDelegate.h"

 #import "AnnotationViewController.h"

 @implementation AnnotationAppDelegate


 @synthesize window=_window;

 @synthesize viewController=_viewController;

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary      *)launchOptions
 {
  // Override point for customization after application launch.

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Please Help..Under tight deadline Thanks.

Comment: Just started with Swift and already under tight deadline – you are ambitious :) But why would you want to add AppDelegate.m? There is already AppDelegate.swift.

Comment: Should have never jumped in this soon!